# creating windows 8.1 apps on Windows 8

Tags: winjs, windows-8.1

I would like to know if it is possible to create win 8.1 apps with WinJs 2.0 (where the hub, search, back button, etc is included) on a machine with Windows 8 or do i have to install the preview of Win 8.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the preview of Windows 8.1 along with the version of Visual Studio for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install preview on Win 8.1 as WinJS 2.0, relies of features introduced in IE 11 (mutation observers etc).